# How to optimize MongoDB to better use disk space?

Tags: mongodb, optimization

**UPDATED**

We have a growing MongoDB database where the load is composed mostly of inserts. It is a two shards database with three collections and MongoDB is currently version 2.6.6. Each shard is a replica set with two nodes and one arbiter.

By analyzing how disk space is used with `db.stats()` these numbers are found:

```
shard0:
   dataSize: 95 Gb
   storageSize: 99 Gb
   fileSize: 107 Gb

shard1:
   dataSize: 109 Gb
   storageSize: 112 Gb
   fileSize: 121 Gb
```

Partitioning is done by shard key which is based on a date. Effectively shard0 is filled with new data while shard1 remains stable by data usage. Occasionally we update the shard key to a newer date and data migrates from shard0 to shard1.

Padding factor on all three collections is set to 1 which should make new data allocation efficient, where each document insert should occupy the same amount as the size of the document itself. However there is a certain amount of "wasted" space that seems pretty large for a database that should be fairly compacted.

Here are the data in three consecutive days:

```
 Shard  | Data Size | Storage Size | File Size
-----------------------------------------------
 shard0 |    90 GB  |    93 GB     |    101 GB
 shard0 |    92 GB  |    95 GB     |    103 GB
 shard0 |    94 GB  |    97 GB     |    105 GB
```

File size reported by MongoDB is about 11 GB larger than data size (this is 12%).

According to this [link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/#faq-disk-size) part of that space could be attributed to preallocated data files. Three (3) collections by 2 GB will at maximum consume 6 GB. Record deletions are extremely rare and could account for wasted space in kilobytes. What about the `oplog` and `journal`, do they account in some of the size parameters or not?

What are we missing? And how this 5 GB (11 GB - 6 GB) is actually being used? Can it be compacted?

Here are the results of `db.stats(1024*1024*1024)` command:

```
{
        "raw" : {
                "rs0/l0.example.com:27018,l1.example.com:27018" : {
                        "db" : "logdata",
                        "collections" : 5,
                        "objects" : 30222965,
                        "avgObjSize" : 3409.2183424094887,
                        "dataSize" : 95,
                        "storageSize" : 99,
                        "numExtents" : 106,
                        "indexes" : 10,
                        "indexSize" : 6,
                        "fileSize" : 107,
                        "nsSizeMB" : 16,
                        "dataFileVersion" : {
                                "major" : 4,
                                "minor" : 5
                        },
                        "extentFreeList" : {
                                "num" : 0,
                                "totalSize" : 0
                        },
                        "ok" : 1
                },
                "rs1/l2.example.com:27018,l3.example.com:27018" : {
                        "db" : "logdata",
                        "collections" : 4,
                        "objects" : 22676428,
                        "avgObjSize" : 5185.006179632877,
                        "dataSize" : 109,
                        "storageSize" : 112,
                        "numExtents" : 99,
                        "indexes" : 8,
                        "indexSize" : 6,
                        "fileSize" : 121,
                        "nsSizeMB" : 16,
                        "dataFileVersion" : {
                                "major" : 4,
                                "minor" : 5
                        },
                        "extentFreeList" : {
                                "num" : 0,
                                "totalSize" : 0
                        },
                        "ok" : 1
                }
        },
        "objects" : 52899393,
        "avgObjSize" : 4170.319437597327,
        "dataSize" : 204,
        "storageSize" : 211,
        "numExtents" : 205,
        "indexes" : 18,
        "indexSize" : 12,
        "fileSize" : 228,
        "extentFreeList" : {
                "num" : 0,
                "totalSize" : 0
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: If you only insert documents and newer update them, then you could use [`noPadding` allocation strategy](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/collMod/#noPadding) to optimize DB size.

Comment: The 20% is definitely padding, one other option open to you if you are able to use 3.0.0 is to import your data to wired tiger and use gzip compression

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using? If MongoDB 3.x, what storageEngine?

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny if padding factor is set to 1, shouldn't the result be the same as noPadding?

Comment: @Sammaye padding factor is set to 1 on all three collections. Shouldn't then the documents be without any paddings (empty space)?

Comment: Yes sorry, I didn't read that right, I jumped on the bandwagon. Can you give us an actual stats() output instead of doctoring it?

Comment: @Sammaye I will in few days update this question with actual output. We have started yesterday to transform the database to a sharded and now it is in the middle of the transform. After transformation is finished, will update with actual numbers

Comment: Hmm your shards have not balanced too well, though I already notice you must have some very big objects cos your average object size relates to only 74.9GB per shard. But I am really not sure about this size use. I would expect 3GB more than storage for pre-alloc, even a Google search using some keywords I know does not turn up any decent results

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use Mongo's new [WiredTiger](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.0/) storage engine. 
For me it reduces the disk space usage by 75%

Comment: The data itself is mostly binary and compressed (like images) so we guess the benefit would not be so large.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are missing the fact that mongo also preallocate storage for a future use:

> The total size in bytes of the data files that hold the database. This
>   value includes preallocated space and the padding factor. The value of
>   fileSize only reflects the size of the data files for the database and
>   not the namespace file.

You can read more about each of the numbers [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/dbStats/).

Comment: Padding factor is set to one which if we understand correctly, MongoDB should allocate exact space as required by the document being inserted. Regarding the preallocated storage, there are three collections and if understood correctly, the maximum could be 3 x 2 Gb = 6 Gb. Still the 13Gb are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Well the data-set is going to grow as you feed it, but I would at your size at the very least shard each collection to it's own mongo instance possibly even machine, while this will not directly affect the size (it may make it slightly larger), the distribution will give you insight as to which of the three collections individual rates of growth are and you should see better throughput (assuming you do not use a single storage for all servers)

Comment: Sharding is an obvious pathway. However, we are concerned about efficiency in disk usage.

Comment: Apologies, What I was explaining was how to use sharding, which would positively benefit your scale, to monitor per collection growth and gain insight into the growth and where the 20% was coming from, you are not buying candy; you are looking into a complex issue you cannot explain, so sometimes you need to be less direct.